# Dynamically reading/assigning values to form using loop

Tags: javascript, html, forms, for-loop, dynamic

I have this problem with reading/assigning value to text input using a loop dynamically.

Here's how it was declared:

```
 if ( $myrow[9] > 0 )
  { $dsl_ctr=$dsl_ctr+1;
    print "<input type='hidden' name='old_dsl_cost_".$dsl_ctr."' value='".$myrow[9]."'>";
    print "<td align='right'>&nbsp;".number_format($myrow[9],3,'.',',')."&nbsp;</td>".
          "<td align='right'><input type='text' size='5' name='new_dsl_cost_".$dsl_ctr."'>&nbsp;</td>"; 
  }
```

Saying that I have the following input text namely:

```
 old_dsl_cost_1           new_dsl_cost_1
 old_dsl_cost_2           new_dsl_cost_2
 old_dsl_cost_3           new_dsl_cost_3
```

I'm having an error accessing it with this statement:

```
for (ctr=1;ctr<=max;ctr++)
 {
   document.a.new_dsl_cost_['ctr'].value = eval(document.a.old_dsl_cost_['ctr'].value) + 
                                           eval(document.a.dsl_cost.value);
 }
```

above statement in loops should be:

```
 document.a.new_dsl_cost_1.value = eval(document.a.old_dsl_cost_1.value) + 
                                   eval(document.a.dsl_cost.value);
```

I need the loop and the counter because the numbers are not definite.

Google is not much of a help at this time :(

Comment: I would like to help but don't understand your question very well.  You can get a reference to an input field using document.querySelector, for instance, and then use the value property to get and set it's value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#htmlattrdefvalue

Comment: i will work on how to make proper reply in a while but thanks for taking a look into my issue

Comment: Can you share a fiddle showing your full JS code? I suggest that you set `old_dsl_cost_1` (etc.) as element `id` instead of `name`, then access the input field values with `document.getElementById('old_dsl_cost_' + ctr + ').value`. Also, instead of `eval()`, try using `parseInt()` for string -> number conversion.